# bypass a low voltage shut off

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator

[image]

Is there a way to disconnect or bypass a low voltage shutdown operation? I have a factory made electronic shooting gallery (toy) that runs on 4 AA batteries. I want to run it to a steady 6VDC supply from a power converter that plugs into 110VAC so there is no more replacing the batteries. The target (receiver) has an on/off switch on the rear. If it is turned on, you can shoot the target all you want as long as it is consistent.

But if you leave the target ON and idle (don't shoot it) for more than a couple of minutes, it turns off. Turn the switch off and then on again and it works/receives the shots again. I have tried this with batteries and a steady 6VDC power supply and it continues to go off after non-use for a couple of minutes. I want it to stay on all the time, unless I flip the switch to the off position.

Could it be something different since it still has the same problem with a steady, unwavering power supply? Is there a way to bypass whatever is causing this?

Comment: That's not a low voltage shutoff. Its a power-saving feature intended to save your batteries in case you forget to turn it off.

Comment: If you don't know the internals of the toy, either you have something "dummy shooting" at the target or you cycle the power once in a while. Power cycling is probably the easiset. A small microcontroller and a transistor switch would probably be enough. Maybe add a LED to signal when power cycling is about to commence.

Comment: Why three close votes "this question is about repair of electronic devices"? Do you guys even read the questions you downvote? Jim, if you want some help you need to open your device and take some photos. brhans has it right, it's a power-saving feature, you might be able to exclude it but we need to see the circuit.

Comment: Hey Jim your photo looks quite good to me, would you please explain what the wires on the left are connected to? I think the timing thing is embedded in the microcontroller, the black blob on bottom right, so there's little you can do about it. Olin's answer will work and is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I agree with the reply about it being to reserve battery life. The red & black wires go to a small motor that kicks the fake bottles off the top of the target when shot. The yellow & white go to the on/off switch, the green wire goes to the battery supply.

Comment: Well you could just add a simple normally closed push button in series with the power button. When you push the button you reset the timer and you're all good.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with low voltage.  It sounds like a feature to turn itself off after you haven't used it for a while to avoid killing the batteries.

This logic is probably encoded in a microcontroller deep inside the product, so is not something you will be able to change realistically.  Without getting into the details of the device that we can't know about, you have to trick the existing logic somehow.

Perhaps you can install a button on the front that interrupts power when pressed.  This glitches the power to wake up the device, so it will be on while.  This could be automated, but that could get annoying if it power cycles and resets just as you are shooting.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answers. How could I make it an automatic thing? To do it manually, I could just flip the existing switch off then on again, but I'm trying to figure out a simple way to automate it, so I just shoot when ready. Funny thing is, is that this feature is not on the gun/transmitter.